# Auto-run CD that opens a video?

Tags: video, burning, compact-disc, autorun, autoplay

I want to create an auto-run CD that will play a video without needing any codecs. Is there software that can do this for me? Or would I have to write something myself?

Comment: Windows, Linux or MacOS?

Comment: Microsoft Windows. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to create an auto-run CD that
>   will play a video ...

**[MakeInstantPlayer](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Authoring-tools/Authoring-Related/MakeInstantPlayer.shtml)** is a tool for creating self-running video files, based on the **MPlayer** engine.

[image]

> This is very useful for distributing
>   videos, as the user doesn't need any
>   additional software for playback. As
>   MakeInstantPlayer uses the MPlayer
>   engine for playback, it supports
>   almost any existing video format.
>   MakeInstantPlayer uses NSIS to pack
>   everthing to one single EXE file.

*MakeInstantPlayer is open source freeware.*

> ... without needing any codecs.

MPlayer does require codecs, but they don't have to be installed: to ensure the movie will play everywhere, check the box **Include Codecs** so the codec required to play the movie will be included in the single EXE file.

to create a CD that will autorun the movie would require an AUTORUN.INF file similar to:

```
[autorun]
open=your_video.exe
icon=your_video.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Media Player Classic as the autorun program, and add the video file as an argument to the player. Not sure about licensing issues on this though.